# Rails/MySQL insertion rollback on .create to database table with console

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm following Kevin Skoglund's Rails 5 Essentials on Lynda.com, and I've run into a problem I can't seem to diagnose. I'm just trying to add in a new Section into my sections table, using the rails console.

When I type the following into the console:

```
section = Section.create(:name => 'Section One', :position => 1)
```

I get the following:

```
(0.4ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I'm trying to insert that into the following table: [image]

Here is my section model:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :section_edits
end
```

I don't see why this insertion shouldn't work, as there aren't any attributes that can't be null. The table sections' rows are empty as well.

[image]

Any reason this doesn't work that any of you can come up with? Seems like a pretty cut and dry insertion, yet for some reason it doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe is the `belongs_to :page` that is requiring a `Page` instance.

Comment: Cool! That worked. Thanks :)

Comment: when you see rollback happening in console, print the section.errors.messages in next line to see details about why the create failed.